# A 2d array from two given lists

Tags: python, python-2.7, data-structures

I have 2 lists

```
x = [7,6,4,9, ...]
y = [1,2,3,5, ...]
```

I would like to create a 2d array out of those lists where the result would like [[x,y],[x,y] ...]

```
[[7,1],[6,2],[4,3],[9,5], ...]
```

Answer (score 3):

In Python 2.7

```
zip(x,y)
```

Python 3.x

```
list(zip(x,y))
```

Output:

```
[(7, 1), (6, 2), (4, 3), (9, 5),......]
```

Comment: This produces a list of tuples.  The original question asked for a list of lists...

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
[list(z) for z in zip(x, y)]
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
x = [7,6,4,9]
y = [1,2,3,5]
i=0
list = []
for entry in x:
    list.append([x[i],y[i]])
    i = i+1
```